# Barplot line overlay ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to overlay a `geom_bar` with additional line `(name ~ long)` that is `ordered` (continuously increasing) on the barplot of `pop` value `aes(name,  pop)`.

Here is attempt including data and replicate script. As can be seen the intended red line is not present in the graph:

```
# load data
    
  library(maps)
  data(world.cities)
    
# data
  set.seed(42)
  some.data <- data.frame(cod=floor(runif(100)*100), name=world.cities$country.etc[1:100], long=world.cities$long[1:100], pop=world.cities$pop[1:100])    
        
# or oder
  some.data.order <- with(some.data, some.data[order(long), ])

  ggplot(some.data.order, aes(name,  pop)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_smooth(method = stats::loess,
                formula = name ~ long,
                color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.25,
                level = 0.5, span = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are after.

`geom_smooth` requires numeric inputs so have converted names to numeric factor. The `long` values are factored by 20000 so they appear on the plot. So there would be a case to add a secondary y axis for the `long` line.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
data(world.cities)

ggplot(some.data.order, aes(name,  pop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(as.numeric(factor(name)), long * 20000), 
              method = "loess",
              color = "red",
              se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20000, name = "long"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>